# How to save some text into string including whitespaces?

Tags: c++, string

I have a problem with C++, shown at the simple program below:

```
int main()
{
    string n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<n;
    return 0;
}
```

I try to save some text into string, but when I write more than one word, it is saved only to the first space sign.

Input:

```
abba abc abd
```

Output:

```
abba
```

Expected output:

```
abba abc abd
```

Can it be solved with `cin`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
std::string str;

std::getline( std::cin, str);
```

`getline()` is the member fucntion of istream class, which is used to read string with spaces

Comment: `std::getline()` is a free function (not a member of the `istream` class) that can be used to read unformatted input from any `std::istream`. The member function `std::istream::getline()` is a completely different function. I suggest that you edit the answer slightly.

Answer (score 5):

The extraction operator `>>` will stop its input conversion at white space.

You nee to use the function `std::getline`, to read a complete line:

```
std::getline(std::cin, n)
```

will do as you expected-

Answer (score 2):

> Can it be solved with `cin`?

No

But it can with [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)